# API resource for determining all address holders of a contract

Tags: etherscan, explorers, explorer-api

I would like a RESTful API for viewing all addresses which holds a balance of a specific contract.

It seems that etherscan.io deprecated this feature, or I'm looking at the wrong endpoints

Are there any services that do this? Other block explorers with APIs?

Comment: What do you mean by 'holding balance of a specific contract" ? Is this about holding tokens from an ERC20 contract ?

Answer (score 0):

[This endpoint](https://docs.amberdata.io/v1.0/reference/tokens) by Amberdata.io would do the trick!

Request:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://web3api.io/api/v1/tokens/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d/holders/latest' \
  --header 'x-api-key: <x-api_key>'
```

Response:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "title": "OK",
  "description": "Successful request",
  "payload": [
    {
      "tokenAddress": "0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d",
      "holderAddress": "0xb1690c08e213a35ed9bab7b318de14420fb57d8c",
      "timestamp": 1554161757000,
      "holderFirstTimestamp": "2017-11-23T18:44:21.000Z",
      "numTokens": "215378"
    },
    {
      "tokenAddress": "0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d",
      "holderAddress": "0x68b42e44079d1d0a4a037e8c6ecd62c48967e69f",
      "timestamp": 1554156091000,
      "holderFirstTimestamp": "2018-03-06T19:03:17.000Z",
      "numTokens": "171892"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

It returns a list of every address that holds that token. In this case every address that has Cryptokitties.

Hope that helps!

Comment: for the low low price of $796 per month! no it doesn't help. Ended up parsing all addresses that transact to and from a token contract from the block height it was created. Not a real solution for casual use.